# How to calculate disk cost for a specific Feature in wix UI?

Tags: wix, wix3

I want create own SetupTypeDlg using wix default dialogs to show the disk costs for Typical/Complete installation depending on features to install in that section.
I am using WIX 3.0 for User Interface.

[link text](http://www.wixwiki.com/index.php?title=CustomizeDlg)
I want CustomizeDlgItemSize from this dialog.
but I am not able to pull it out for required features.

How to calculate disk cost for a specific feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a selection tree control disk costing is performed automatically by Windows Installer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371604(VS.85).aspx

On the same dialog with the selection tree you can create a static text control which has a **SelectionSize** subscribed control event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371602(VS.85).aspx

If you don't want to use a selection tree, a solution is a custom action. By using custom code you can try to determine the feature sizes and set them in installer properties. These properties can then be used in your package UI.

Another solution is to use hard-coded values. In this case you can determine the sizes manually before building the package and set them yourself in the package UI.